# How to reduce transparency of <header> ,the position of which I have assigned as fixed?

Tags: html, css

`CSS of my header{
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.781);
text-align: right;

```
position: fixed;
opacity: 1;

height:56px;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
```

}`
When I scroll down my web page , other content of the page are little visible behind my header....
How can I remove this Transparency of my header ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using rgba in CSS of the header,

In rgba , a stands for alpha i.e opacity as a number between 0.0 (fully transparent) and 1.0 (fully opaque)

In your case use

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); 
text-align: right;
```

Comment: I think this answer is enough, if not, then share the whole code.